# Item validation both at item and record level

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I'm new to Oracle Forms.

I want to be sure that an item considered "valid" as soon as inputed, at time T0 (thru When-validate-item trigger), is still valid when the relevant row is inserted (or updated) and committed at time T1, where T1-T0 could be, say, a long coffee time, during which the system status may have changed so as to invalidate the item.

I thought about coding specific item-level program unit to be called both by WVI trigger and by a higher level trigger. Which one would be best?

Is this double check a common practice in Oracle Forms?

Note: I need to double-ckeck both in case of form layouts and in master-detail layouts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to double-check on normal validation. Then a when-validate-item trigger will be enough to make sure it is valid. If you need to check a field that needs also a value in another field, for example a person is a firm it needs only a lastname otherwise it needs a first and a lastname then you could use the when-validate-record trigger to check this.

If your data depends on the system date or other data that might be inserted/updated in the time between validate and commit. You should place your validation on the pre-insert and pre-update trigger. Then it will always fire just before the insert or update.